# Hive SQL to determine subset

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

My company has a software to construct some SQL in Hive SQL. The **left** part is flexible and could be any type (e.g. String) as I have freedom to store or convert. The **right** part is not flexible as it can only be like this in a SQL statement: `('a','b','c')`. So I can prepend it with a function like `concat_ws('a','b','c')` but I cannot remove the parenthesis `(..)` around it.

I want to do 2 scenarios:

1. `('a','b')` **is a subset of** `('a','b','c')`. So this will return `TRUE`. However, `('a','d')` **is a subset of** `('a','b','c')` will return `FALSE` as `d` does not exist in the right side.
2. `('a','b')` **has at least one element in** `('a','b','c')`. This returns `TRUE` since either `a` or `b` is on the right side. But `('d','e')` **has at least one element in** `('a','b','c')` will be `FALSE`.

Is there a way to do this without writing UDF or adding 3rd party UDFs?

I was thinking about converting them to lowercase and compare as a trick such as `'ab'` is substring of `'abc'` (ugly workaround):

```
select instr(concat_ws('|',sort_array(array('B','A','C'))),'A|B')>0;
```

return `TRUE`

```
select instr(concat_ws('|',sort_array(array('B','A','C'))),'A|E')>0;
```

return `FALSE`

But the second case is harder. I am guessing if:

1. I can concat two string
2. Break into array via `|`
3. Combine unique values into array
4. Count final array elements if less than two combined in the beginning

Strange but just an idea!

Comment: where do you have this data?what are the datatypes?what have your tried so far?

Comment: My modified question is above

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the Built-in Table-Generating Functions ([UDTF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inTable-GeneratingFunctions(UDTF))). For instance `explode` will create one row per element of your array `explode(array ('a', 'b'))`. From there on you can use the usual SQL-fu.

Full example, actually works for both cases:

```
 with abc as (
   select explode(array('a', 'b', 'c')) as l
 )
 select
     count(*) = size(array('a', 'b')) as case1
   , count(*) > 0 as case2
 from
   abc 
 where l in
   ('a', 'b') -- true, true
   -- ('a', 'd') -- true, false
   -- ('d', 'e') -- false, false
 ;
```

Comment: Can you give complete example for #2?